# Dynamic scale image width in android

Tags: android, android-layout, canvas, bitmap, imageview

I have two 1 PX sized images which needs to be set as per the their respective percentage values. 
It takes 100 PX width only. 
My need is to set this image view in a particular layout.

[image]

Need help
Thanks.

Comment: 1 pixel? Those seem a little small... Have a look at a Linearlayout and weight. Then put two ImageViews in there!

Comment: nine patch image and weight concept will do that

Comment: Thanks - StackOverflowException